# Partial integration and substitution

Tags: integration, substitution

I have trouble solving

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{\lambda^2}\cdot e^{-(x/\lambda)^2/2}\,dx$$

Somehow I end up with a '2' too much. The correct result is lambda * sqrt(pi/2).

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You are missing the limits of integration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra $2$ in your parts integration. Let's see:

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty 
\frac{x^2}{\lambda^2} e^{-\frac{(x/\lambda)^2}{2}} dx &= -\int_0^\infty x \frac{d}{d x} e^{-\frac{(x/\lambda)^2}{2}} dx \\ \\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{(x/\lambda)^2}{2}} dx \\ \\
&= \sqrt{2}\lambda\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{(x/\lambda)^2}{2}} d\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}\lambda}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\lambda
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Where did the sqrt(2) come from in front of the integral?

Comment: @canbus I've multiplied and divided by $\sqrt{2}$ in order to convert the integral to $\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2} d u$. I admit I did it in horrible _1920s physics_ notation.

Comment: Doesn't the e^(...) term have to be integrated for the partial integration? $$\int u*v' = u*v -\int u'*v $$... the u*v term will be zero, I got it, but we need the integration of v' in the last integral or not?

Comment: Sure, but I think you're missing a $2$ from the primitive of $v$.